# String length counter in NASM

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

everyone. I wrote a program in NASM calculating length of a string supplied as a variable:

```
section .data
    ; str1 db '12345678901'
    str1 db '123456789012'

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, str1
    mov ecx, -1

.loop:
    inc ecx
    cmp byte [eax + ecx], 0
    jne .loop

.done:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, ecx
    int 80h
```

When I run the program with the first string (commented in this listing) it returns the correct value 11. With the second string it's 13 - 1 more than it should be. I have no idea why it is so. It's assembled on a 64-bit machine. I tried inspecting it with GDB, but I don't see the point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str1 db '123456789012'
....    
cmp byte [eax + ecx], 0
```

Your string has no NUL terminator. Change it to `str1 db '123456789012',0`.

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks, Michael. I'm still wondering, though, what caused the difference in output in these two cases.

Comment: Probably "chance". In one instance you just happened to get a byte with the value 0 just after the last character in your string, and in the other you didn't. Depending on the circumstances it wouldn't be chance at all. For example, you might have an executable format where sections are padded to meet a certain alignment constraint, and a linker which fills unused bytes in a section with certain values. But in general it's best not to rely on such implementation-specific details.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to calculate a string's length is to use the scasb instruction:

```
xor   rax,rax      ;so all of ax is 0 for return value
mov   ecx,0x03fff  ;limit scan length
cld
repne scasb
sub   ecx,0x03fff  ;sub by the scan length
neg   ecx
dec   ecx          ;minus one for rep going too far by one
mov   eax,ecx      ;C functions return in ax register
```

The `0x3fff` is my limiting value so that the `scasb` doesn't go too far in case of a string that's not `0` terminated. You can set it to any value you like, in fact many libraries use `ecx` at its max of `0xffffffff`. But you must always be sure the strings you give it are `0` terminated! If not, it will return the limit value as the string's length (if it doesn't fault first).

Comment: Thanks, Bob. I'll check it out. My example wasn't really meant as a real-life length counter, just a toy program :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sub and neg you may use mov -1 in ecx: and then not

```
xor al, al      ; the byte that the scan will compare to is zero

mov ecx, -1     ; underfow will set the maximum number of bytes

cld             ; CLD (STD) clears (sets) the Direction flag, data goes onwards (backwards).
repne scasb     ; while [rdi] != al, keep scanning
; The REPNZ prefix (which is more readable in the REPNE form) repeats the scas as long as the comparison is false (REPeat while Not Equal) and ECX > 0. It also decrements ECX automatically in every iteration. ECX has been initialized to the longest possible string so that it doesn't terminate the loop early.

not ecx         ; Since ECX counts down from 0xffffffff (also known as -1), the resulting length will be -1-ECX
sub ecx, 1      ; len--

mov eax, ecx    ; ret = len

ret
```